# Cannot import matplotlib on Spyder after conda installation

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, conda, spyder

I installed `matplotlib` on Anaconda Prompt with `conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib`.

However, when I run `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` on Spyder 4.1.5 (with Python 3.7), I got an error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'
```

Before getting this error message, I installed `matplotlib_scalebar` with `conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib-scalebar`. I had no issue importing `matplotlib.pyplot` before this, and I suspect that installing this might have caused the problem.

Under `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`, I have folders with the following names:

- matplotlib
- matplotlib-3.0.2.dist-info
- matplotlib-3.3.2.dist-info

I'm not sure if having different folders (`3.0.2` and `3.3.2`) is an issue here.

How can I fix this `No module` issue?

Comment: are you sure the Spyder interpreter is pointing to the same Python version as your conda install?

Comment: yes, and I figured that `import matplotlib` works, but `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. I removed and reinstalled `matplotlib`, and now it works.